# Grab brush or snake hook

Tags: sculpting

I am on a sculpting expirience and i can not really find any difference on these two brushes , grab[g] and snake hook brush. Also what brush is better for extending a mesh? ( i read blender manual,still cant understand the difference).

Answer (score 4):

With **dynamic topology**, to extend the mesh with additive geometry, use the *snake hook* brush. Use the grab brush, if you want to make small tweaks to geometry without changing the topology.

[image]