# I am new to blender and when I sculpt it isn't smooth like in videos I have watched

Tags: sculpting

Whenever I watch a video on blender and they use a sculpting brush it is smooth but whenever I use a sculpting brush it comes out very sharp and polygonal, What do I do? I was watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ujfwXiQ1_II&t=334s And I am trying to use the grab tool here is an image[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab brush won't subdivide mesh while sculpting with Dyntopo, it works on already existing geometry of the mesh and is expected only to move geometry (as mesh is lowpoly so far there aren't any details for Grab brush to pull out).
If you want to grab and subdivide while moving to get necessary geometry use Snake Hook brush instead; it was implemented [as of Blender 2.66](https://en.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.66/Dynamic_Topology_Sculpting#Snake_Hook).

See also [Grab brush or snake hook](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106940/grab-brush-or-snake-hook) and [sculpting brushes in blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/sculpting/tools.html)

Answer (score 0):

On the *Tool* panel (on the left of your 3D View, displayed with <kbd>T</kbd>), have you tried to:

- Decrease the Detail Size?
- Enable the Smooth Shading?

[image]

Comment: I wasnt able to fix it by turning on smooth shading or changing the detail size